# how transform my c# code to js method replace

Tags: c#, javascript, string, replace

in c# I have this row of code

```
this.Office.Name.Replace(@"""", @"\""")
```

I want in js to use this string

I tried like this:

1. > var test =  <%=this.Office.Name.Replace(@"""", @"\"""); %>;
   >   Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected    Line 574:
   >   string test = <%=this.Office.Name.Replace(@"""", @"\"""); %>;
2. without @

   > string test = <%=this.Office.Name.Replace("""", "\"""); %>;
   >
   > Compiler Error Message: CS1010: Newline in constant
3. > string test = <%=this.Office.Name.Replace('"', '\"'); %>;
   >
   > Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected

Comment: The javascript Tag on your question is a bit misleading, if the question is with about the **Replace** Methode of C#.

Comment: After reading your question again, i'm not quiet sure what your are after. A conversion of a c# code to JS? Or you are having problems Converting C# strings into valid JS? Nevertheless for both approaches there is a solution here. :)

Comment: do you have a solution yet, or do you still need some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since it is javascript **var** for declaring Variables (The Backslashes should work)

```
var test = <%=this.Office.OfficeName.Replace("\"", "\\\"") %>;  
// NO SEMICOLON in the asp.net TAGS <%= ... %>
// 3 Backslashes the first one escapes the Second one, 
//    the Second is literal(since it was escaped),
//    the third escapes the double quot.
```

But i would look at the possible Values, to be sure there aren't any edge cases, where this conversion might not work.

If you want to do the Replacing with Javascript and not with c#, go with the answer of Pid

Answer (score 1):

```
anystring.replace(/""/, "\\\"\");
```

And you get `\""`.

With this:

```
anystring.replace(/""/, "\\\"\\\");
```

you get `\"\"`

Even easier:

```
anystring.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
```

Every `"` in `anystring` will be escaped with `\"`.

Comment: This is the javascript replacing Function you are explaining, the one of the question is in C#.